# Pausing An Android Animation: Problems With interpolatedTime

Tags: java, android, android-animation, interpolation

I am working on an animation that can be paused.

As such I have subclassed an `Animation` class.

The key method I am overriding is the `applyTransformation`. The normal way animation is done, is you use the interpolated time to do your animation.

However, this cannot be paused.

As such I am creating my own interpolated time and using that to determine animations because if its paused, I can keep this adjusted interpolated accurate.

What I do is I keep track of the system time, and measure the distance between elapsed frames and use that as my true interpolation time. Because if its paused, then I keep updating the `_lastAccumulatedTime` without applying the interpolation until its unpaused.

The problem is my values and Androids values are off! The first problem is the first 2 or 3 times `applyTransformation` is called, the sent interpolated time is 0! (Hence I check for that and ignore in a vain attempt to get my interpolated time to sync with Androids passed one).

However after that, my calculated and Androids passed interpolation times are sometimes the same and sometimes different. Here is a log example (each empty line is a new frame call):

> Custom interpolation 0.2762763 Their interpolation 0.25225225
>
> Custom interpolation 0.37237236 Their interpolation 0.4024024
>
> Custom interpolation 0.44144145 Their interpolation 0.45345345
>
> Custom interpolation 0.5045045 Their interpolation 0.5045045
>
> Custom interpolation 0.5405405 Their interpolation 0.5555556
>
> Custom interpolation 0.5675676 Their interpolation 0.6066066
>
> Custom interpolation 0.6156156 Their interpolation 0.6576577
>
> Custom interpolation 0.6696697 Their interpolation 0.7057057
>
> Custom interpolation 0.7207207 Their interpolation 0.7567568
>
> Custom interpolation 0.7717718 Their interpolation 0.8078078
>
> Custom interpolation 0.8198198 Their interpolation 0.8588589
>
> Custom interpolation 0.8798799 Their interpolation 0.9099099
>
> Custom interpolation 0.972973 Their interpolation 0.957958
>
> Custom interpolation 1.024024 Their interpolation 1.0
>
> Custom interpolation 1.078078 Their interpolation 1.0

Theres ends up at a perfect 1, where as mine has rounding issues. As you can see this this case, I ended with 7.8% variance. It also calls the transformation twice in a row when it should already be done (i.e. the two back to back 1.0 calls)??

Here is the initialization:

```
public RadialProgressBarAnimator(RadialProgressBar progressBar, float newFillPercent, Callbacks.VoidCallback onSecondTick, Callbacks.VoidCallback onFinish)
    {
        _lastAccumulatedTime  = System.currentTimeMillis();
        _accumulatedTickTime  = 0;
        _oldFillPercent       = progressBar.getFillPercent();
        _newFillPercent       = newFillPercent;
        _progressBar          = progressBar;
        _onFinish             = onFinish;
        _onSecondTick         = onSecondTick;

        // Default interpolation is not linear, so set interpolation to linear
        setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    }
```

Here is my override:

```
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation)
{
    if (_paused || interpolatedTime == 0)
    {
        _lastAccumulatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return;
    }

    // Add interpolated time to accumulator and fire onSectionTick callback
    // if time has exceeded 1 second
    _accumulatedTickTime  += System.currentTimeMillis() - _lastAccumulatedTime;
    _totalAccumulatedTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - _lastAccumulatedTime;

    if (_accumulatedTickTime > TimeConstants.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
    {
        _accumulatedTickTime = 0;

        if (_onSecondTick != null)
        {
            _onSecondTick.callback();
        }
    }

    _lastAccumulatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    float adjustedInterpolatedTimed = (float)_totalAccumulatedTime / (float)getDuration();

    float deltaFillPercent = (_newFillPercent - _oldFillPercent) * adjustedInterpolatedTimed;

    Log.d(TAG, " Custom interpolation " + adjustedInterpolatedTimed);
    Log.d(TAG, " Their interpolation " + interpolatedTime);
    Log.d(TAG, "\n\n ");

    float newTimeAdjustedFillPercent = _oldFillPercent + deltaFillPercent;


    this._progressBar.setFillPercent(newTimeAdjustedFillPercent);
    this._progressBar.requestLayout();

    if (newTimeAdjustedFillPercent == _newFillPercent && _onFinish != null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Animation finished");
    }
}
```

Kudos if you've kept up so far!

My question is:
1. Why are my calculated and interpolated times different than Androids
2. How the heck can I properly pause an Animation?

**Work around**

This does the trick:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14829837/3324388

But doesnt explain why my calculated interpolation is different than Androids. ¯_(ツ)_/¯